# Regex link from google results

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I was trying to get **URLs** from Google results, but the Google api doesn't allow getting more than the first 100 results, so I thought of copying the Google content, pasting it to a file and using preg_match_all to get the results. Unfortunately I am not good with regular expressions.

Can someone help me with this? The main problem is that the links do not have "http://".

```
$body="PHP – Wikipedia, wolna encyklopedia
        pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP‎
        PHP jest najczęściej stosowany do tworzenia skryptów po stronie serwera WWW, ale może być on również używany do przetwarzania danych z poziomu ...
        Możliwości - Historia - Moduły - Składnia
        PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor
        php.net/‎Tłumaczenie strony
        Server-side HTML embedded scripting language. It provides web developers with a full suite of tools for building dynamic websites: native APIs to Apache and ...
        Downloads - Documentation - A simple tutorial - News Archive - 2012
        PHP: Downloads
        php.net/downloads.php‎Tłumaczenie strony
        Binaries for other systems. We do not distribute UNIX/Linux binaries. Most Linux distributions come with PHP these days, so if you do not want to compile your ...
        PHP Tutorial - W3Schools
        www.w3schools.com/php/‎Tłumaczenie strony
        Provides basic to advanced PHP functions. Users can also learn how to integrate PHP with other languages such as MYSQL, AJAX, and XML.
        Kurs PHP
        phpkurs.pl/‎
        Kurs programowania w języku PHP. Kurs ten ma za zadanie zaznajomić osobę kompletnie nieobeznaną z tym językiem na tyle, aby sama była w stanie napisać ...
        Podstawy - Operacje na plikach - Ciągi znakowe (stringi) - Tablice";
    preg_match_all('/^(www\.)?[a-z0-9_\-]+.[a-z]+$/', $body, $match);

print_r($match);
```

Result:

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) )
```

Can you help me fix it?

Comment: Do you know what `^` and `$` mean? They're not just decorators to be used in every regex.

Comment: I think that is beginning and the end of the line. I tried with this '/^(www\.)?[a-z0-9_\-]+.[a-z]+[^<]*$/' also. Cen you specify what is wrong with it?

Comment: In your excerpt the links don't start at the line beginning. There are spaces in front. And `$` only works on line ends if the `/m` flag is used. Else `^$` pertain the subject start/end, not lines.

Comment: Okey so after adding /m flag nothing happened. I tried with sth like this: `'/^[^<]*(www\.)?[a-z0-9_\-]+.[a-z]+[^<]*$/m'`

Comment: Regular expressions aren't the best method for extracting data from HTML, but what you posted doesn't have any HTML tags. What happened to the HTML? If you provide the HTML, I can provide a much better solution.

Answer (score 0):

This will match most basic url patterns, and accept any end of the url. I tested it on your example input and it seems to work like you want.

```
preg_match_all('/((?:(?!-)[a-z\d-]+[^-]\.)+[a-z]{2,6}.*)/', $body, $match)
```